# Use different relay in postfix

Tags: email, postfix

In our application, we send different kind of mails. On a broad view we can generalize it in two category,

1. Mails which monitor the health of the app.
2. Mails which we send to end user.

Is there any way(Setting some header/configuring some parameter in postfix), such that for the same sender address, we can use different relay host?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In postfix, you can use [transport_maps](http://www.postfix.org/transport.5.html) to specify different relay hosts for different domains. In file `/etc/postfix/main.cf`, you need to include a line:

```
transport_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/transport
```

The transport maps file has the following syntax:

```
# Syntax: .domain transport:relay_host
# Specifies specific domains for local delivery
mydomain1.com :
mydomain2.com :

# Specify domains that need to be relayed through 192.168.1.1
anotherdomain1.com relay:192.168.1.1
anotherdomain2.com relay:192.168.1.1
```

Don't forget to run `postmap transport` to generate the `.db` file and then reload/restart postfix process.

Comment: Thank you, but what if the different relay hosts require authentication?

Answer (score 6):

Transport maps (in Khaled's answer) can change the relay of mail based on the domain.

You can also use [header_checks](http://www.postfix.org/header_checks.5.html) and [body_checks](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#body_checks) to change transports (and perform other actions) based on matching headers and content found in the body of the email.  These can be regex or hash based. My example below is regex based.

In `/etc/postfix/main.cf`:

```
header_checks = regexp:/etc/postfix/header_checks
```

In `/etc/postfix/header_checks`:

```
/^Subject: Host [a-z0-9]* is down!/ FILTER relay:192.168.1.1
/^Subject: [^ ]* has posted a new blog entry./ FILTER relay:192.168.1.2
/^Message-ID: <[0-9a-z]*@dbserver.local>/ FILTER relay:192.168.1.1
/^Message-ID: <[0-9a-z]*@mydomain.com>/ FILTER relay:192.168.1.2
```

The `body_checks` work the same way as the `header_checks`.

You can set arbitrary headers in your app if you want something unique to filter on.

Comment: Thanks Ladadadada, hope to use these approach for some advance filtering.